# Calling a powershell function with a global hotkey

Tags: powershell, scripting, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I want to use a function from my Powershell script by triggering a global hotkey (the combination Ctrl+Shift+F12) which is registered and unregistered by my script. I need to access a .NET object created by my script. In pseudo code:

```
$object_i_need = New-Object SomeClass
register_hotkey "Ctrl+Shift+F12" hotkey_func

function hotkey_func { do_something_with $object_i_need }

wait_for_keypress
unregister_hotkey
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If the .Net object supports `Add_Keydown` (like System.Windows.Forms.Form) you can do something like this...

```
$objWhatever.KeyPreview = $True
$objWhatever.Add_KeyDown({
     if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter"){
         hotkey_func{}
      } 
})
```

Comment: it doesn't, unfortunately (it is a ProcessInfo object).